# iOS 17.0.3: Web Speech recognition does not work properly

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

I have iPhone 15 Pro with iOS 17.0.3 version.
Web speech recognition does not work most of the time on Safari.
Microphone turns on properly, but what you speak loud and clear on the microphone does not get transcribed into text properly.
Other versions of ios (above 16) worked fine so far.
Sometimes, it picks up what I say perfectly. But it is very rare, almost one out of ten times.

Here is what I know so far:

- Meaning of 'it does not work': when you turn on the mic and speak 'What a beautiful day today', it just outputs 'Relate'. Sometimes nothing at all.
- When it does not work, it does not work no matter how many times you retry it and vice versa.
- When you exit Safari and come back after a while, it suddenly works perfectly, picks up whatever you say accurately even on a low voice or from a distance.
- It only occurs on iPhone 15 Pro running iOS 17.0.3, Safari browser.

What I tried:

- checking Safari's microphone permissions, all are OK. Site permissions are also OK
- checking battery percentage, it is full
- no Bluetooth devices are connected

Here is the web speech demo link: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

Is it a known issue or is there anything I can do to solve this issue?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.